# How do I reference data from another collection in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I reference data from another collection in MongoDB?
At frontend I create a form where the user can select `reporting_manager_id` and when the user submits the form then the `reporting_manager_id` and `reporting_manager_name` are stored in the database. `reporting_manager_name` taken from **ReportingManager** collection.

**employeeModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullname:{
        type:String
    },
    father_name:{
        type:String
    },
    date_of_birth: {
        type: Date
    },
    email:{
        type:String
    },
    mobile:{
        type:String
    },
    phone:{
        type:String
    },

    present_address:{
        type:String
    },
    permanent_address:{
        type:String
    },
    employeeImage:{
        data: Buffer
    },
    pan_id_no:{
        type:String
    },
    aadhaar_no:{
        type:String
    },
    employment_id:{
        type:Number
    },
    location:{
        type:String
    },
    joining_date:{
        type:Date
    },
    designation:{
        type:String
    },
    reporting_manager_id:{
        type:String
    },
    employment_status:{
        type:String
    },
    employment_type:{
        type:String
    },
    probation_end_date:{
        type:Date
    },
    release_date:{
        type:Date
    },
    createdAt:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Employee",employeeSchema);
```

**reportingToModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const reportingToSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    reporting_manager_id:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
    },
    reporting_manager_name:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("ReportingManager",reportingToSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a foreign reference id from another collection.
When you need to fetch documents with joined documents from another collection, try use [.populate()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-populate-method/) or [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)